# Using the css3 animation property 'alternate' for multiple elements of the same type

Tags: html, css, animation

I've set up 3 divs to animate in a wavelike fashion. The animation itself works fine but when trying to reverse the animation using the *alternate* property is when I run into problems. Is there a something I'm not doing to get them to reverse in a wavelike motion?

http://jsfiddle.net/Jn875/3/

**HTML**

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
@-webkit-keyframes wave {
      0%, 100% {-webkit-transform: scaleY(1);}
      50% {-webkit-transform: scaleY(2);}
}

@-moz-keyframes wave {
      0%, 100% {-moz-transform: scaleY(1);}
      50% {-moz-transform: scaleY(2);}
}

@-ms-keyframes wave {
      0%, 100% {-ms-transform: scaleY(1);}
      50% {-ms-transform: scaleY(2);}
}

@-o-keyframes wave {
      0%, 100% {-o-transform: scaleY(1);}
      50% {-o-transform: scaleY(2);}
}

@keyframes wave {
      0%, 100% {transform: scaleY(1);}
      50% {transform: scaleY(2);}
}

body {
    padding: 150px;
}

div {
    -webkit-animation: wave 1s alternate;
    -moz-animation: wave 1s alternate;
    -ms-animation: wave 1s alternate;
    -o-animation: wave 1s alternate;
    animation: wave 1s alternate;
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom; 
    -moz-transform-origin: bottom;
    -ms-transform-origin: bottom;
    -o-transform-origin: bottom;
    transform-origin: bottom;
    background: gray; 
    display: inline-block; 
    margin-left: 20px; 
    height: 100px; 
    width: 100px;
}

div:first-of-type { 
     margin-left: 0px;
}

div:nth-of-type(2) { 
    -webkit-animation-delay:.5s;
    -moz-animation-delay:.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay:.5s;
    -os-animation-delay:.5s;
    animation-delay:.5s;
}

div:nth-of-type(3) { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    -os-animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
}
```

Comment: You can't mix and match vendor prefixes. if you are defining a `-moz` keyframe, use the -moz` prefix on the properties inside the keyframe as well.

Comment: I think I might've changed the code up as you put your comment up. Does it look correct circa this post?

Comment: Nope...look at -moz keyframe,  you are using -webkit properties and so on.

Comment: Wow. Can't believe I didn't catch that before. Thanks.

Comment: Offhand I think you need individual timings too but it's not clear what you are after as a final result.

Comment: Basically have the animation start from the last div to the first one, once the initial animation is over.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48506/discussion-between-carl-edwards-and-paulie-d)

Comment: Did you guys figure out what Carl wants? Any feedback?